# Get last loading element in Webpage

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing a selenium code. Here I want to get the page loading time. And the code is as below.

```
FirefoxDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver();
fd.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Start time is " + startTime);
fd.get("myurl");
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("End time is " + endTime);
System.out.println("total time is " + (endTime - startTime) + " for i " + i);
timeTaken += (endTime - startTime);
fd.close();
System.out.println("Total tyime is " + timeTaken);
System.out.println("Avg time is " + (timeTaken / 10));
```

Here my question is , I want to use an Explicit TimeWait. To use that, i saw in tutorials that i need to get some web element and use `waitTill` condition, But here i'm unable to understand which element loads last, Please let me know how can i find this, so that i can get more accurate results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the explicit wait for the element you want to interact with.
For example, if you're on a web page and need to click the Submit button, you will specify an explicit wait for the Submit button. E.g.:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("submitbutton")));
```

Or you can wait for the element to be clickable:

```
public WebElement isElementLoaded(WebElement elementToBeLoaded) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(item)));
    return element;
}
```

For what you were mentioning, to wait for the last element on the page to be loaded, that's more of an Implicit wait, because you know that more elements will take a longer time to load and you specify a longer implicit loading time.

Comment: Pretty old, I know...but the above is great if the item you are waiting for is is all you have to wait for, but...there are times that the button is visible and interactable, but the rest of the page content hasn't loaded and navigating away too soon breaks the process. In this case, you would still want to know the last element to load so you know what to look for...or you could just use the JavascriptExecutor j = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
j.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");